Not able to mock a class used within ProcessElement of an Apache Beam pipline
I can mock a static method in a class from my test case, but when I test pipelines, the same is not mocked. The same class is referenced while static mocking directly from my test case and also while mocking pipelines (the static methods are called from @ProcessElement annotated methods i.e they will be called when pipeline.run() command is called).
Here is an example to explain it in more details:
Class to be tested:
public class BuildResponse extends DoFn<String, String> {

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c, OutputReceiver<String> out)
    {
        String element = c.element();
        String output = response(element);
        out.output(output);
    }

    private String response(String s) {
        var time = TableUtil.getCurrentTS(); // I cannot see my mock object when I debug leading to incorrect output
        return time + s;
    }
}

Class with static method:
public class TableUtil implements Serializable {
    private static final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.ENGLISH).withZone(ZoneId.of("UTC"));

    public static String getCurrentTS(){
        return dateTimeFormatter.format(Instant.now());
    }
}

Test Case:
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@MockitoSettings(strictness = Strictness.LENIENT)
class BuildResponseTest {

    private static MockedStatic<TableUtil> tableUtilMockedStatic;
    private static String currentTime;
    @BeforeAll
    static void setUp() {
        currentTime  = Instant.now().toString().concat("test");
        tableUtilMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(TableUtil.class);
        tableUtilMockedStatic.when(TableUtil::getCurrentTS).thenReturn(currentTime);
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void tearDown() {
        tableUtilMockedStatic.close();
    }

    @Test
    public void BuildResponseProcessTest() throws Exception{
        tableUtilMockedStatic.when(TableUtil::getCurrentTS).thenReturn(currentTime);
        System.out.println("currentTime -> "+ currentTime);
        System.out.println("table time -> "+ TableUtil.getCurrentTS()); // this gives the correct mocked output 

        TestPipeline p = TestPipeline.create().enableAbandonedNodeEnforcement(false);

        String s = "Element";

        PCollection<String> input = p.apply(Create.of(s));

        PCollection<String> output = input.apply(ParDo.of(new BuildResponse()));
        String expectedOutput = currentTime + s;
        PAssert.that(output).containsInAnyOrder(expectedOutput);

        p.run().waitUntilFinish(); // this when runs gives the incorrect output
    }
}

Error:
java.lang.AssertionError: ParDo(BuildResponseNew)/ParMultiDo(BuildResponseNew).output: 
Expected: iterable with items ["2024-10-22T05:13:02.035ZtestElement"] in any order
     but: not matched: "2024-10-22T05:13:04.755ZElement"

I tried using InjectMocks for BuildResponse class but the outcome was the same. I also tried using inline static mock but the outcome was the same.
I was expecting to static mock the TableUtil.getCurrentTS() call in BuildResponse class, how to achieve such mock strategy.
Can someone please help me with what is the right approach to test such pipelines?
The question that marked this post duplicate, I have also tried that workaround but was not able to mock (also it requires changes in main code). My exact question revolves around if I have to do some changes in the test code what possibilities are there that I do not have to change the main code.
Also, PowerMockito.mockStatic used to work, but while migrating to junit5 MockedStatic somehow is not working.
Also, tried DI approach, without any wrapper. Still throwing the same error.
Just to note that this technique removes static call completely, and the issue remains same, so it is not just occurring because of static method call.
If someone want to have a look, I have uploaded the code to github.
Github link for testcase

Let me guess: TestPipeline  invoke static method in other thread?

It seems like this only, the thread context is changing, but I am not able to confirm this via debugger, is there any way to confirm this without writing whole multithreading code?
